# Need of @Transactional with advice and pointcut

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Do we still have to use @transactional annotation in the methods if we mentioned those methods in tx:advice and point cut in AOP? Or does @transactional is a replacement for  advice and point cuts?

Comment: It's a replacement(an alternative).

Answer (score 0):

It is just a different way that makes using declarative transactions easier to work with.
The downside is that you are adding the transactional annotation to the actual code.

In most cases that is not a problem, but consider a scenario where you have one Repository class that you want to be used on multiple datasources.

If you used annotations for declarative transaction handling, you would need some duplicate code, while in the case of `tx:advice` you could easily make as many objects of the class transactional with their own transaction manager, without ever touching the code.

Another obvious scenario where you could not add `@Transactional` is when you can't modify the source code.